# Problems with the zip function: lists that seem not iterable

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

I'm having some troubles trying to use four lists with the zip function.
In particular, I'm getting the following error at line 36:
`TypeError: zip argument #3 must support iteration`

I've already read that it happens with not iterable objects, but I'm using it on two lists! And if I try use the zip only on the first 2 lists it works perfectly: I have problems only with the last two.
Someone has ideas on how to solve that? Many thanks!

```
import numpy
#setting initial values
R = 330
C = 0.1
f_T = 1/(2*numpy.pi*R*C)
w_T = 2*numpy.pi*f_T
n = 10
T = 1
w = (2*numpy.pi)/T
t = numpy.linspace(-2, 2, 100)

#making the lists c_k, w_k, a_k, phi_k
c_karray = []
w_karray = []
A_karray = []
phi_karray = []

#populating the lists
for k in range(1, n, 2):
    c_k = 2/(k*numpy.pi)
    w_k = k*w
    A_k = 1/(numpy.sqrt(1+(w_k)**2))
    phi_k = numpy.arctan(-w_k)
    c_karray.append(c_k)
    w_karray.append(w_k)
    A_karray.append(A_k)
    phi_karray.append(phi_k)

#making the function w(t)
w = []

#doing the sum for each t and populate w(t)
for i in t:
    w_i = ([(A_k*c_k*numpy.sin(w_k*i+phi_k)) for c_k, w_k, A_k, phi_k in zip(c_karray, w_karray, A_k, phi_k)])
    w.append(sum(w_i)
```

Comment: Looks like `A_k` and `phi_k` are numeric values - do you maybe mean to zip `A_karray` and `phi_karray` instead?

Comment: The error is very clear as `A_k = 1/(numpy.sqrt(1+(w_k)**2))` it is not an iterable thus you can't use it as an argument for `zip` function !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you mistyped the last 2 elements in `zip`. They should be `A_karray` and `phi_karray`, because `phi_k` and `A_k` are single values.

My result for `w` is:

```
[-0.11741034896740517,
 -0.099189027720991918,
 -0.073206290274556718,
...
 -0.089754003567358978,
 -0.10828235682188027,
 -0.1174103489674052]
```

HTH,

Germán.

Comment: Ohh so bad! I was so much tired that I didn't notice that stupid thing! Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want `zip(c_karray, w_karray, A_karray, phi_karray)`.  Additionally, you should produce this once, not each iteration of the `for` the loop.

Furthermore, you are not really making use of `numpy`.  Try this instead of your loops.

```
d = numpy.arange(1, n, 2)
c_karray = 2/(d*numpy.pi)
w_karray = d*w
A_karray = 1/(numpy.sqrt(1+(w_karray)**2))
phi_karray = numpy.arctan(-w_karray)
w = (A_karray*c_karray*numpy.sin(w_karray*t[:,None]+phi_karray)).sum(axis=-1)
```